# hover on an image, the image opacity and color of title below the image changes...also when the title becomes two line, it ruins the format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I currently have an image and the title below that image. Thing I'm trying to achieve is when I hover on the image I want the color of text to be changed. and I want the opacity of an image to be changed as well. 
When I hover on the title, I want the color of that text to be changed to the same color that's been used when I hover on the image.
To clarify, I'm trying to make it like this;http://www.viralnova.com/science/

I have a code like this

```
<div class="row">
<article>
  {% for news in newsInCat %}
  <div class='col-sm-4'>

    <div class="content">
    <figure class="story-image">
      <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}'><img src="{{news.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="360" height="267"></a>
    </figure>
      <div id="forever "style="margin-bottom:30px;">
      <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}' style="text-decoration:none; color:#282E5C;"><center><h4 style="font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;">{{news.title}}</h4></center></a>
  </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</article>
</div>
```

How should I do it to achieve my requirements?

also when the title becomes two lines...the posts are becoming like this

```
AAA AAA AAA
... AAA AAA
AAA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #282E5C;
}
.content{
  width:360px;
}
.content:hover a {
  color: red;
}

.content:hover img {
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <figure class="story-image">
    <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}'><img src="http://media.galaxant.com/000/459/563/340x252-1459957623.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="360" height="267"></a>
  </figure>
  <div id="forever " style="margin-bottom:30px;">

    <h4 style="font-size: 18px;
              font-weight: 400;"><a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}'>{{news.title}}</a></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh man i copied this class to your example website wait i am updating my answer

Comment: okkk?please let me kn

Comment: @mikebraa i have update my answer see this

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use jQuery. It's simple to implement and to understand.

Add a class to your title element like this:

```
<div class="row">
<article>
{% for news in newsInCat %}
<div class='col-sm-4'>
<div class="content">
<figure class="story-image">
  <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}'><img src="{{news.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="360" height="267"></a>
</figure>
  <div id="forever "style="margin-bottom:30px;">
  <a class='box-title' href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}' style="text-decoration:none; color:#282E5C;"><center><h4 style="font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;">{{news.title}}</h4></center></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>{% endfor %}
</article>
</div>
```

Now use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img-rounded").hover(function(){
      $(this).css("opacity",1);
      $(".box-title").css("color","red");
    });
    $(".box-title").hover(function(){
      $(this).css("color","red");
    });
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.img-rounded{ opacity:0.8; }
.box-title{ color:black; }
```

Don't forget to add the the jQuery script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: any example?I looked into few examples and failed multiple times I have decided to upload here

Comment: check and see if it works the above code

Answer (score 1):

Give your image a class name, suppose `man` then in css give `.man:hover` opacity with value, then next give title a class name, suppose shi , then in css give `.man:hover .shi`a color that u want

```
.man:hover{
opacity: 0.5;
}
.man:hover .shi{
color: #2222;
}
```

Comment: oh thank you any idea why my format gets changed when the post has two lines?

Comment: Did it helped u,  u got the solution from it ?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple image opacity. When you say opacity:1 your opaque is 100% but when you say 0.8 it is 80% and that is the effect you got from website provided so your css should look like this:

```
    .img-rounded {
        opacity:0.8;
        }
      a:hover {
            color:blue;
            }
       h4:hover{
        color:red
}
```

Comment: I want the color of the text to be changed as well

Comment: I updated it. Take a element or h element and add hover state in style. and that is pretty much it. You need to select element and change it's state.